# how to properly do the following update MYSQL statement?

Tags: mysql, string, csv, sql-update, where-clause

i have a string with the following value

Germany,Sweeden,UAE

and i have an mysql row that have a value of one of this separated string with comma

as example a Country Row with a value Sweeden .

i have tried to use this sql statement to update a targeted row where its value is like one of this string separated with comma

hence if the row have a value of sweeden it should be updated sense sweeden value is include in the comma string

```
UPDATE CountryList SET Time= '100' WHERE Country LIKE '%Germany,Sweeden,UAE%'
```

but i couldn't update the targeted row using this syntax. any idea what is the correct syntax i should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `find_in_set()`:

```
update CountryList 
set time = 100 
where find_in_set(country, 'Germany,Sweeden,UAE')
```

This checks if `country` matches any of the values in the comma-separated row given as second argument to `find_in_set()`.

Note that I removed the single quotes around the literal `100`: if `time` is a number, then treat it as such (if it's a string instead, then keep the quotes).